# Understanding Index creation in MySQL - Timestamp field

Tags: mysql, indexing

I want to understand how index is created in MySQL - **meaning** if its a `TimeStamp` field - will it create a hash of the `TimeStamp` field and store it **or** just store the literal Value of the timestamp. Since timestamp has a precision of milliseconds - each index will be unique, then how effectively the index creation is done ? Any **internals** that will help me understand this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's Timestamp is essentially a decimal number that has between 0 and 6 decimal places *as per your declaration*.  For a millisecond example:

```
SELECT NOW(3), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(3));
+-------------------------+------------------------+
| NOW(3)                  | UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(3)) |
+-------------------------+------------------------+
| 2023-08-11 22:57:58.167 |         1691819878.167 |
+-------------------------+------------------------+
```

You could think of it as being the number `1691819878.167`.  The value is seconds from the start of the epoch, based on UTC.  It, like `DATETIME` takes between 5 and 8 bytes, depending on the fractional seconds desired.

The value is stored *as is* in the Data's BTree and in any index that includes that column.

A BTree (actually B+Tree) index on a timestamp column is the same as on any other number or string -- an ordered list of key + pointer to the row in the data's BTree.  That "pointer" is a copy of the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table.

`FULLTEXT` and `SPATIAL` indexes are different than the normal BTree INDEX.

BTrees are partially self-rebalancing.  Don't worry about it unless you are deleting a million rows.

It is probably unsafe to make a `TIMESTAMP` column `UNIQUE` -- after all two things *could* occur in the same second (or even microsecond).

As with other datatypes, you can have a 'composite' index that includes multiple columns as the 'key'.

No "hash" is involved with any indexing method in MySQL's InnoDB Engine.  (Engine=MEMORY uses Hash and there is an exception with MariaDB.)

B+Trees love to handle ranges -- whether they are integers, timestamps, floats, strings, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an index on a TIMESTAMP field or any other data type, MySQL doesn't store a hash of the value or the literal value itself as the index key. Instead, it uses a data structure called a B-tree (balanced tree) to organise and store index keys. B-trees are commonly used in databases because they provide efficient ways to search, insert, and delete data.

**What is an index key?**

An index key is a value or set of values extracted from one or more columns of a database table and used to build an index data structure. The purpose of an index key is to facilitate fast data retrieval and efficient querying of the table's data. Each index key corresponds to a specific row in the table.

Comment: whats an index key ?

Comment: I think this is misleading a bit. If you store a timestamp in a (usual) index, the actual value is stored (well, the byte representation of it), not a derived or shorter value. That seems to have been the question. Also, since for innodb, the "actual table" is *also* a btree, you would say that storing a value in a table doesn't actually store that value in the table? Mentioning btrees is probably a good idea, since op is interested in how indexes work, but it's more like "data is stored in this data structure" than "since a specific data structure is used, it's not the original value anymore"

Answer (score 0):

Indexes in databases are like bookmarks that help find rows with certain column values efficiently. Without an index, the database has to search through the entire table, starting from the beginning, to locate the needed rows. This becomes slower as the table gets bigger. But if the table has an index for the specific columns being searched, the database can quickly figure out where to jump to within the data, without scanning everything. This is way faster than reading each row one by one.

Mainly there are two types of index mechanisms in [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimization-indexes.html). They are B-Tree Indexes and Hash Indexes.

**B-Tree Index Characteristics**

- **Structure:** B-tree (Balanced Tree) indexes are organized as a balanced tree structure where each node can have multiple keys and child pointers depending on the order (Maximum number of children a tree’s node could have) of the tree. This structure ensures that the tree remains balanced and optimized for range queries.
- **Key Distribution:** B-trees are well-suited for cases where the data distribution is not uniform, and they handle a wide range of data values efficiently.
- **Support for Range Queries:** B-tree indexes are particularly effective for range queries (e.g., *SELECT WHERE column BETWEEN x AND y*), as they allow for efficient traversal of data in a sorted order.
- **Insertion and Deletion:** B-trees handle insertions and deletions efficiently while maintaining the balance of the tree. However, frequent insertions and deletions can lead to fragmentation over time.
- **Use Cases:** B-tree indexes are commonly used for columns with high cardinality (many distinct values) and for queries involving range conditions.

**Hash Index Characteristics**

- **Structure:** Hash indexes use a hash function to map keys to specific locations (buckets) in the index. This allows for direct access to the desired data without the need for traversing a tree structure.
- **Key Distribution:** Hash indexes work well when the data distribution is uniform and the hash function effectively distributes data across buckets.
- **Exact Match Queries:** Hash indexes are optimized for exact match queries (e.g., SELECT WHERE column = x), as they provide constant-time access to the data if the hash function is well-distributed.
- **Insertion and Deletion:** Hash indexes can be efficient for insertions and deletions when the hash function is well-designed and collisions (multiple keys mapping to the same bucket) are minimized. However, dealing with collisions can impact performance.
- **Use Cases:** Hash indexes are often used for columns with low cardinality (few distinct values) and for scenarios where exact match queries are common.

**Comparison:**

- **Query Types:** B-tree indexes are versatile and support both range queries and exact match queries efficiently. Hash indexes excel at exact match queries but may not perform well with range queries.
- **Data Distribution:** B-trees can handle non-uniform data distribution effectively, while hash indexes perform best when data distribution is uniform.
- **Insertion/Deletion:** B-trees handle insertions and deletions well, especially for high cardinality columns. Hash indexes can perform well for insertions/deletions if hash collisions are minimized.
- **Memory Usage:** B-trees generally consume more memory compared to hash indexes due to their tree structure.
- **Suitable Data Types:** B-trees are suitable for a wide range of data types, while hash indexes are more suitable for integer or string columns with limited cardinality.

**Answer**

For a TimeStamp field, a B-tree index is generally a better choice than a hash index. B-tree indexes provide efficient support for both range queries and exact match queries. Since timestamps often involve queries for specific time ranges or ordered results, a B-tree index can provide better performance and more flexibility in these scenarios.

When you create an index on a TimeStamp field in MySQL, it uses a B-tree indexing (default indexing mechanism) algorithm. This means that the actual timestamp values are stored in a sorted structure, not their hash.

Comment: Hash indexing is not used by MySQL.  BTree is usually as fast as Hash.  Furthermore, Hash _cannot_ handle range queries.